# The vertices of $G$ are colored with 3 colors such that each vertices adjacent to vertices colored with only one of 3 colors, then why $\chi(G)=2$?

Tags: graph-theory

The vertices of $G$ are colored with 3 colors in such a way that each vertices adjacent to vertices colored with only one of 3 colors, then why $\chi(G)=2$?

I'm not sure if I understand this statement correctly. But let $v$ be the vertices that is colored $1$, so all neighborhood of $v$ is color $2$ or $3$. The term each vertices adjacent to vertices colored with only one of 3 colors confused me, is that mean all neighborhood of $v$ can't be colored both $2$ and $3$? What if $x,y$ are neighborhood of $v$, and $x$ and $y$ are adjacent?

Comment: If this were true all graphs had $\chi(G)=2$. Proof: Color all vertices with the same color.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: I think we're still assuming the ordinary rule that the endpoints of an edge must br two different colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement must mean that there is no vertex of color 1 that has neighbors *both* of color 2 and color 3, and so forth.

*Hint:* What does this imply about the colors of a *connected component* of the graph?

Comment: oh, if that's what the statement mean then $G$ is either a path $P_n$ for $n \geq 2$ or $C_k$ for $k$ is even, right?

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif: No, there's nobody saying a vertex can't have degree $>2$. Just that all of its neighbors (however many or few there are) share a color.

Answer (score 0):

In a proper $k$-coloring of a graph there exists a vertex which is adjacent to $k-1$ colors, else we can rearrange and use lesser number of colors. Since no vertex in your graph is adjacent to two different colors, $\chi(G)<3$. So $\chi(G) = 2$, since a vertex is joined to a vertex with different color (or simply because there is an edge).